# USING WITH CHECK OPTION IN SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I've already created a view with a check option that restricted salary as the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW EMPVIEWSAL
AS (
  SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID, LASTNAME, SALARY FROM EMPLOYEES
  WHERE SALARY >= 5000
)
WITH CHECK OPTION CONSTRAINT EMPVIEWSAL_CK;
```

Then, I add a new column and also modified other column as the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW EMPVIEWSAL (EMPLOYEE_ID, "COMPLETE NAME", JOB_ID, BONUS)
AS (
  SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID, LASTNAME||','||FIRSTNAME, JOB_ID, SALARY + .1*SALARY FROM EMPLOYEES
);
```

My question is that after the second statement, it never restricted the salary be >= 5000, and in the output I have salary below that. Why the check option that I've already added to my view did not restrict the salary for my second statement?

I appreciate that if you could give me advice regarding the matter.

Comment: Because.... you recreated the view without the filter (or the check option)?

Comment: you mean every time for adding or modifying the view I need to use the filter??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't *modifying* the view, you are redefining it. The only real difference of `create or replace view` versus using `drop view` followed by `create view` is that any privileges granted on the view are retained. (And it won't fail if the view already exists, of course).

You have to recreate the view with the same filter in the query, and any other options you need:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW EMPVIEWSAL (EMPLOYEE_ID, "COMPLETE NAME", JOB_ID, BONUS)
AS (
  SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID, LASTNAME||','||FIRSTNAME, JOB_ID, SALARY + .1*SALARY FROM EMPLOYEES
  WHERE SALARY >= 5000
)
WITH CHECK OPTION CONSTRAINT EMPVIEWSAL_CK;
```

The `with check option` clause isn't restricting the query results to those with salary below 5000, that's the `where` clause. [See the documentation for what that does.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/CREATE-VIEW.htm).

---

Incidentally, I'd avoid using quoted identifiers, as you have to quote them wherever they are referred to. It would be better to have:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW EMPVIEWSAL (EMPLOYEE_ID, COMPLETE_NAME, JOB_ID, BONUS)
...
```

or something similar.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. so how can I modify the view and make those change withoute using create or replace view that be restricted by the filter i've already added to the view.

Comment: You can't change the view query without using `create or replace` and including everything you need in the new definition. The filter is part of the query. You're telling it to use a different query which doesn't have that filter. You can't have both. A view is just a stored query really. There is no equivalent to adding a new column to an existing table.

Comment: Thank you I got the right idea right now. But my last question,what if I want to modify a view for just adding a with check option or adding just with read only??is there aother way not just using create or replace view?

Comment: You can use [`alter view`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/ALTER-VIEW.html) to make it read-only. I'm not sure why redefining the whole thing is an issue though.